# What is the purpose of --url-base=/wd/hub when starting chromedriver server?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, codeception

According to the [codeception's documentation](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver), you can run tests in Chrome Browser by connecting to the ChromeDriver directly without using Selenium Server.

You first need to [install ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started) and then launch it by running the command `chromedriver --url-base=/wd/hub`.

What is the purpose of `--url-base=/wd/hub`?  Can't find it anywhere.

**UPDATE**
In the [ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome documentation](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started/getting-started---android), `wd/hub` is mentioned under the FAQ section without any explanation of what that is.

Comment: This url prefix is used by Selenium, so my guess is that this option makes Chromedriver behave more like Selenium.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The purpose of `--url-base` is to define the base entry point for all the received commands.

The default entry point with chromedriver is `/`.
For instance to get all the sessions the client would send:

```
http://localhost:9515/sessions
```

But by default, the client (RemoteWebDriver) sends the commands to `/wd/hub`:

```
http://localhost:9515/wd/hub/sessions
```

Thus you need to set this flag so that the client can communicate with chromedriver.